# "Use the 'new' keyword to create an object instance" error in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net

I am getting this error "use the 'new' keyword to create an object instance.  (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) "
I checked similar questions on this forum but could not find a satisfactory answer. 
what I am trying to achieve is import string value of 1 into registry subkey `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\TEST`

What I noted during Debugging is that "regkey" appears to be set to Null at all the lines where it is used. 
I am setting

```
regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\TEST", True)
```

, still not sure why its 
value is not picked up by program.

How do I implement New keyword to create an object instance ? 
I am using "Imports Microsoft.Win32" at the top level in program.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click
   Dim regkey As RegistryKey
   regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\TEST", True)
   regkey.SetValue("TEST", "1", RegistryValueKind.String)
   regkey.close()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you try to open a subkey of HKEY_CURRENT_USER with Registry.LocalMachine and I bet this gives back a null reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HKEY_CURENT_USER\Software\MyApp\TEST`, which does not exist. Hence, [RegistryKey.OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `null` (`Nothing`).

You should

1. fix your code (`Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\...")` will probably do what you want), and
2. add a null check (`If regkey Is Nothing Then ...`) between lines 2 and 3 that handles the problem gracefully.

Comment: Hi Heinzi, and Steve, thanks for showing me the mistake. I revised as per your instruction and the registry was imported..

Comment: Hi Heinzi, and Steve, thanks for showing me the mistake. I revised as per your instruction and the registry was imported..

[CODE]
  Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Software\MyApp\TEST", True)
        regKey.SetValue("TEST", "1", RegistryValueKind.String)
  regKey.Close()
[/CODE]

Heinzi, Like you mentioned I will also add the null check just in case.

Comment: If Heinzi solved your issue, please mark the answer. It helps others finding similar solutions...among other things.